# Spinner's style is changed once i open it for the second

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, spinner

I am developing an app where I show a dropdownlist using a spinner.

I used a custom adapter, here is the code:

```
public class DemandeCongeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static final String TAG = "DemandeCongeAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private List<DemandeCongeType> mData;
    protected LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public DemandeCongeAdapter(Context mContext, List<DemandeCongeType> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            typedeDemandeName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.type_demande_name);
        }

        protected final TextView typedeDemandeName;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DemandeCongeType getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_create_demande_conge_custom_spinner, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (position != 0) {
            DemandeCongeType item = getItem(position);

            String name = item.getTypdeDemandeName() == null ? "" : item.getTypdeDemandeName();
            viewHolder.typedeDemandeName.setText(name);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And for the activity code, here is it:

```
private List<DemandeCongeType> congeTypes;
private DemandeCongeAdapter spinnerCongeTypeArrayAdapter;

congeTypes.addAll(new ArrayList<>((List<DemandeCongeType>) responseBody));
congeTypes.add(0, new DemandeCongeType());
spinnerCongeTypeArrayAdapter = new 
DemandeCongeAdapter(DemandeCongeNewActivity.this, congeTypes);
congeTypeSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerCongeTypeArrayAdapter);
congeTypeSpinner.setSelection(Adapter.NO_SELECTION, false);
```

Everything works fine, but when I select the spinner for the first time, it shows the list correctly like this:
[image]

Once I click outside the spinner and I click for the second time on the spinner, I got it like this:

[image]

So I can't the find the problem, please if anyone can help me with that.

Here is the XML code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_type_conge"
    fontPath="fonts/light.otf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```

And for the spinner item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/type_demande_name"
    fontPath="fonts/light.otf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:lines="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/annuaire_hint_color"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This way i have use this in my `Application`.

`XML` Design Code.

`Spinner` set in your `Activity`

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/sp_pen_Category"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
   android:padding="@dimen/margin_10" />
```

This file `XML` File `sp_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title">

</CheckedTextView>
```

This file `XML` File `sp_items.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/black">

</CheckedTextView>
```

This is `Java` code when you fill `spinner`.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adp_sp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity.this, R.layout.sp_items, arr_spinner);
    adp_sp.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sp_list);
    sp_pen_Category.setAdapter(adp_sp);
```

Comment: Thanks @HardikParmar, I will try it but I need to override `setDropDownViewResource`because I have a `custom spinner`